# ObservableCollection<ViewModel> Children (Delete Self)

Tags: c#, mvvm, viewmodel, observablecollection

I have a simple observablecollection of viewmodels which have self-contained logic for that specific view.  Within the view I have an option for deleting, which currently invokes the parent data to refresh/reload.

So -- I'm not a huge fan of passing the parent data context through the constructor, and need a best practice answer.  How can I properly delete this, and have the parent update accordingly?  Can I hook INotifyPropertyChanged to the whole view and have the parent remove this way?

Comment: Show some code, so we can see what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have a simple observablecollection of viewmodels which have self-contained logic for that specific view.

Rule: A viewmodel has no knowledge of the specific view that's using it.

2. Within the view I have an option for deleting, which currently invokes the parent data to refresh/reload.

So u have a ViewModel connected to the View. This ViewModel holds an ObservableCollection. Collections have a Remove(obj) method. So u identify on which Element the Delete is called and stomp it out of the Collection. The Collection will update ur View when u call RaisePropertyChanged(). if u have the displaying part on listening to the ViewModel (Mode=TwoWay). if ur Delete should the Delete the whole Collection u can call Clear() on it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you trying to break the dependency of ChildViewModels from ParentViewModel. You can do that by introducing an interface that will abstract the operation that ChildViewModel need to perform. Then the ChildViewModel will depend on interface and parent will implement it. For example:

```
interface IOwner
{
    void Delete(ChildViewModel vm);
}

class ChildViewModel
{
    private IOwner owner;
    public ChildViewModel(IOwner owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Delete()
    {
        owner.Delete(this);
    }
}

class ParentViewModel:IOwner
{
    public Delete(ChildViewModel child)
    {
         //deletion logic
    }
}
```

You can model IOwner in different ways according to your needs and preferences, other example:

```
interface IOwner
{
    IList<ChildViewModel> Children {get;}
}
```